# Bootstrap navbar active item display border-bottom like blog example

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wold like to change the active:after of the li active item, like the blog example (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/blog/), but in my case, I need a bottom bar instead of a triangle.

The example does this:
.nav

```
.navbar-nav .active:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: " ";
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

Everything I got so far is:

```
.blog-nav .active:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: " ";
    border-right: 10px solid;
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
    border-left: 10px solid;
}
```

the problem is that it doesnt fit the link text.

How can I change this code to look like a rectangle that fits the word with under the link instead of a triangle?

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-nav .active:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: " ";
}
```

If you want to modify how big is the rectangle, just modify height and width as you please

Comment: Is there a way to make the width fit the link length?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what has solved my problem was styling the li.active element instead of .active:after. Thank you so much.